# Continue reading xmlfiles despite errors

Tags: c#, xml

I read several xml files :

```
foreach (XMLFileType doc in docs)
```

But when one file is not correct ( for example : empty ), the process stop.

I want to continue the process but put a log in a file with the error.

When the log is written, the process go on and read the other xmlFiles.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is `XMLFileType`? Where are you actually reading the XML file?

Comment: Add an exception handle try/catch inside the for loop.  The exception is exiting the for loop